# Phpstorm tabs order after "jump to declaration"

Tags: phpstorm

Every time when I open a new file from the "Project" window it always appears in the tab on the right and that's perfectly fine! **BUT** when I use *CTRL + Click (jump to declaration)* it can open a new file in a tab which is located wherever IDE likes (maybe not wherever IDE likes but apparently it remembers the last position of the tab in question and opens it there).

**E.g.** if I have 3 tabs open and I want to go to the declaration of anything that is stored in a different file I'd appreciate this file to be opened at least in a tab on the right from the current tab!

I din't find a solution so far and I must say it's pretty annoying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By chance I found an answer. If you want to make new tabs appear at the end there is a setting in top menu <kbd>Window</kbd> -> <kbd>Editor Tabs</kbd> -> <kbd>Open New Tabs At The End</kbd>

[image: screenshot]

I expected to find it in the settings under <kbd>Editor</kbd> -> <kbd>General</kbd> -> <kbd>Editor Tabs</kbd>. Alas...

**P.S.** The same is valid for IntelliJ IDEA